# UIView constraint behaving differently when using iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a viewcontroller with a UITableView that takes up the majority of the screen. At the bottom of the viewcontroller, I have a `UIView` called `controlView` with some buttons. When the viewcontroller first loads, I set the `NSLayoutConstraint` that manages the height of controlView to 1 so that controlView is not visible.

```
@IBOutlet weak var controlViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
controlViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1.0
```

When a user taps on a tableview cell, I adjust `controlViewHeightConstraint.constant` to make it visible

```
controlViewHeightConstraint.constant = heightConstant  //heightConstant = 65
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This has been working perfectly for the iphone 5, 6, 7, 8, and 8+. However, with the X, when I call controlViewHeightConstraint=1 in `viewDidLoad`, the controlView is still visible. Any idea why it is appearing when it should not be visible.

storyboard setup

[image]

iPhone 8+ before tapping cell

[image]

iPhone 8+ after tapping cell

[image]

iPhone X before tapping cell

[image]

iPhone X after tapping cell

[image]

Comment: Oh boy, it's really hard to see any difference with that many that huge pictures. Please make them smaller.

Comment: sorry ill update it in a min

Comment: Are you using the same iOS version on the different device simulators? And secondly: how are you positioning that controlView? Did you switch over to the new safeArea layout constraint?

Comment: @JanBrinker yes, using the same version of iOS. I set the position and all the constraints in storyboard. Not sure I understand your last question

Comment: @Brosef: since iOS 11 there is a new layout guide called `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. See Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

The main purpose of this layoutGuide was to account for iPhone X differences (rounded corners, the notch, the bottom bar). So as you seem to only have issues with the iPhone X, this might be the reason. Check the constraints in the storyboard and maybe you can change the positioning to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. You should do so anyway with the iPhone X, but it also could solve your problem.

Comment: @JanBrinker looking through the documentation you sent me. Regardless of whether I'm in a safe area or not - if I set the height constant of a UIView to 1, the view shouldn't be visible right?

Comment: @Brosef: I think so, however it still might be related. It could be that iOS has to break some constraints when displaying the view because it finds some constraint conflicts with the height and positioning. Does anything like that pop up in the console when opening the view?

Comment: I think adjusting the height is the wrong strategy. You need to adjust the bottom constraint of your button view so that it moves off the bottom of the screen.  Or perhaps have two constraints. One that sets the bottom of the button view to the bottom of the safe area (buttons visible) and one that sets the top of the buttons to the bottom of the view and then animate the activation/deactivating of the constraints.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was thinking about that too. However, I was considering using the controlViews top constraint and setting it below the screen and adjusting it to move up.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by adjusting the top constraint of the controlView to be below the screen by default and adjusting the constraint to move the view up to become visible. For some reason adjusting the height constraint of the view would not work with the iPhone X. Might be due to complications with the bottom safe area portion of the iPhone X.